# How to loop through array of array of objects and put the data into table in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, fs

I have data like this:

```
Data =
            "Time": "06:04:01",
             location: canada,
            "user": [
                {
                    "name": "Drake",
                    "email": "drake@gmail.com",
                    "age": "16",
                },
                {
                    "name": "jack",
                    "email": "jack@gmail.com",
                    "age": "28",
                },
                {
                    "name": "peter",
                    "email": "sams@gmail.com",
                    "age": "20",
                },
    ]
```

I want to print them with console

I want to loop throught the data and print the data in a a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5U5E.png) . in Node jS

I want to generate file with `fs`(file System library) and generate html file here... with table tags:

```
    str ="<table>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <td>";
        for(let i = 0; i < Data.user.length; i++){
          str+= JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].name);
        }
    str+= "</td><td>"
        for(let i = 0; i < Data.user.length; i++){
          str+= JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].email);
        }
    str+= "</td><td>"
        for(let i = 0; i < Data.user.length; i++){
          str+= JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].age);
        }
 str+= "</td><td></table>"
return str
```

I am geting data like : [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAu5O.png)

The table and everthing is okay there is something wrong with the looping or displaying.
Please help me how can I print them like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGUOl.png). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below solution:

```
str ="<table>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>age</th>";
for(let i = 0; i < Data.user.length; i++){
          str+= "<tr><td>"+JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].name)+"</td><td>"+JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].email)+"</td><td>"+JSON.stringify(Data.user[i].age)+"</td></tr>";
        }
    str+= "</table>"
return str
```

Comment: Thanks, it si working but due to `JSON.stringify()`, in the tables cells I am getting data like `"drake", :peter` with `""` in it: How can I remove it? get only `drake, peter`

Comment: you can use replace regex to avoid unnecessary characters, for eg; `let value='"drake", :peter' ; 
value = value.replace(/[":]/g, "");`